# Log method parameters and return type using Enterprise library logging application block

Tags: enterprise-library, entlib-logging

Is there any way to log method parameter name , its value and return type value using Enterprise library logging application block.
I have provided a code sample below. The requirement is to log it's methods input parameters value and its return type value

```
// Complex Types
public class UserDetails
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int UserAge { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Pwd { get; set; }
}

//Interface
public interface IService
{
    UserDetails GetUserDetails(User ReqUser);
}

//Imp
public class Service : IService
    {

        [LogCallHandler(Categories = new string[] { "General" }, LogBeforeCall = true, LogAfterCall = true ,
         BeforeMessage = "This occurs before the call to the target object",AfterMessage="This occured after method call",IncludeParameters=true)]
        public UserDetails GetUserDetails(User ReqUser)
        {
            UserDetails oUD = new UserDetails();
            oUD.UserName = "hhh" + ReqUser.UserId;
            oUD.UserAge = 100;
            oUD.UserAddress = "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH";
            return oUD;
        }

        #endregion
    }

//Usage
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
    container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
    IService service = container.Resolve<IService>();
    User nUser = new User();
    nUser.UserId = "TTTTT";
    nUser.Pwd = "XXXXX";
    UserDetails mm = service.GetUserDetails(nUser);

}
```

Could anyone please explain how to implement this using Enterprise library logging application block?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-3.0/##PostSharp-3.0.chm/html/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect.htm) to intercept your method calls using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) API.
[OnMethodBoundaryAspect.OnEntry](http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-3.0/##PostSharp-3.0.chm/html/M_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect_OnEntry.htm) method includes [MethodExecutionArgs](http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-3.0/##PostSharp-3.0.chm/html/T_PostSharp_Aspects_MethodExecutionArgs.htm) parameter which provides all the information you need about the method and its arguments.

See [this](http://intelligence4.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/non-intrusive-logging-with-postsharp-and-entlib-v5/) post for a sample logging aspect implementation very close to your requirements.

```
// This method is executed before the execution of target methods of this aspect. 
public override void OnEntry( MethodExecutionArgs args )
{
    // Build method information to log.
    string methodInfo = BuildMethodInformation(args.Arguments);

    // continue with your logging...
}
```

You can get method parameters via [Arguments](http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-3.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp-3.0.chm/html/AllMembers_T_PostSharp_Aspects_MethodExecutionArgs.htm) member of MethodExecutionArgs parameter like this:

```
private string BuildMethodInformation(Arguments arguments)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(_methodName);
    foreach (var argument in arguments.ToArray())
    {
        sb.Append(arguments.GetArgument( i ) ?? "null");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

For method parameters, check [this](http://doc.postsharp.net/postsharp-3.0/##PostSharp-3.0.chm/html/952d27f4-3322-4aac-b1be-b3929e245de3.htm) or [this](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/SOLID-Caching.aspx) samples. They are built for caching but BuildCacheKey/GetCacheKey methods include all the information you need to get argument information of a method.

Comment: Thanks for your information Hasan. Our plan is to replace PostSharp with entlib. So your answer will not work for me.

Comment: I see. Since I don't know your PostSharp constraint, I thought that you can still use EntLib logwriter inside a PostSharp aspect.
Then, if I guess your need correctly this time, you can achieve to use LogCallHandler by following my next answer (because of character constraint in comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use EntLib LogCallHandler by code:

```
container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
    new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>());
```

Or by config file:

```
<unity>
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />
    <namespace name="LoggingCallHandler" />
    <assembly  name="LoggingCallHandler" />
    <container>
        <extension type="Interception" />
        <extension type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity.EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" />
        <register type="IService" mapTo="Service">
            <interceptor type="TransparentProxyInterceptor" />
            <policyInjection />
        </register>
    </container>
</unity>
```

Here, `LoggingCallHandler` is namespace/assembly for your service class. Alternatively, you can define your type alias like this:

```
<alias alias="Service" type="LoggingCallHandler.Service, LoggingCallHandler"/>
<alias alias="IService" type="LoggingCallHandler.IService, LoggingCallHandler"/>
```

See [this](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/439252) or [this](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/349785) discussion for full configuration including logging block configuration.